# Drawing the exact region of the Bitmap in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am working on a Action Script 3.0 application , in which i ill be allowed to load the image and make them draggable.  Consider i am loading the deer image and making it as draggable.
Problem with this is , if i click on the translucent area ( white space around the bitmap ), i dont want the bitmap to draggable.is there any way to draw the deer boundary region exactly without the white space around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BitmapData` methods to get each pixel color, and then, you can either :

- On creation, for each pixel if it's not fully transparent (!= 0) you can draw a point of a Shape, which will be transparent, and make it dragable in place of your bitmap *(as noticed in comment, it will be quite CPU consuming, so use the second method)*
- **On click, get the click coordinate relative to the bitmap, check if the pixel is transparent and make it drag only if it's not.**

In either way, that will be quite CPU consuming. You may also consider convert your bitmap to a vector image (Sprite). This will allow flash to detect real images boundaries.

Comment: The second way is not so CPU consuming, you just do two coordinate translations and one getPixel32() call. Converting a bitmap to a vector might be worse than this.

Comment: Use only second method , it will be fast and good . You will have to check point once , only after click . First method will took lot of memory and cpu on redrawing .

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. i just completed by the second one. i found one more method by using the bitmapfill of the sprite class which draws the bitmap as sprite , but as u said it is bit CPU consuming